# Kotlin Array, List, MutableList .plus() not working

Tags: kotlin, mutablelist

Where am I wrong ?

I use plus() function for adding in end of MutableList Element or List, but its not working. I may use Add() but I spent a lot of time trying understand my bad.

```
fun main() {
    var arr=mutableListOf<Int>(4,5) ;
    var arr2=mutableListOf<Int>(1,3); 
    arr.add(8);
    arr2.plus(arr)
     
    println( arr2.size);
}
```

Result: 2

```
fun main() {
    var arr=mutableListOf<Int>(4,5) ;
    var arr2=mutableListOf<Int>(1,3); 
    arr.add(8);
    arr2.plus(arr)
     
    println( arr2.size);
}
```

Result: 2

With Array and List the same.

[From Kotlin Docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jvcpw.png)

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"? Note that the `plus()` method of `MutableList` does **not** modify the original list, as [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/) says. It returns a **new list** that consists of the elements of the old list, with the new element added. The original list is unchanged.

Comment: For future reference, please just include a link to relevant documentation, instead of a screenshot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kotlin has two different operators for adding to a list:

[plus](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/plus.html) (+), which returns a *new* list containing the original list and the added element or list, and
[plusAssign](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/plus-assign.html) (+=), which *adds* the given element or list to the original list.

So, the correct way to do this would be:

```
var arr = mutableListOf<Int>(4,5)
var arr2 = mutableListOf<Int>(1,3)
arr += 8 // or arr.plusAssign(8)
arr2 += arr2 // or arr.plusAssign(arr2)
 
println(arr)
```